# Unable to get div right-justified using Flexbox

Tags: css, forms, flexbox, bootstrap-modal

I've inherited what I appreciate is a very messy modal and form which I've stripped down to it's most basic structure for the purpose of this question.

I've been having a look at various Flexbox tutorials and questions on S.O. however what looks to be a simple task to right-justify the notes and checkbox has so far eluded me.

```
<div id="flexTest-modal" class="modal-fade-flexTestModal" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="flexTest-modal-title" aria-describedby="flexTest-modal-content">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body pull-left" id="flexTest-modal-content">
                <div class="form-body">
                    <form method="POST" id="flexTestForm" action="${SampleAction}">
                        <ol class="nobullet">
                             <li><label class="label flexTestOption" for="${TestValue}"><input type="radio" name="RadioInputName" value="${TestValue}" id="${TestValue}" />    Test Value</label></li>
                        </ol>
                             <div class="to-right-justify" id="right-justified-id">
                                 <h5 for="flexTestNotes">Notes</h5>
                                 <label class="switch" class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" class="right-block"><div class="slider round" ><span class="on">On</span><span class="off">Off</span></div></label>
                             </div>
                </div>
                     <div class="modal-footer">
                     </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

    .form-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;

}

.to-right-justify  {
  justify-content: space-between;
  float: right;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kilo1981/qzhofsdk/25/

I need the list item: "Test Value" to be left justified (where it is currently is fine). However I need the "notes" heading at the same level as the list item, only right justified, and the on/off checkbox below the "notes" heading.

Comment: You want to make the `form` itself a flex container, because that has the two items you want to display in a row as children. Add `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` to the form, and remove flex from `.form-body` (otherwise the form will not go over the full width automatically, which I assume you want.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.to-right-justify {
  justify-content: space-between;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexTest-modal" class="modal-fade-flexTestModal" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="flexTest-modal-title" aria-describedby="flexTest-modal-content">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body pull-left" id="flexTest-modal-content">
        <form method="POST" id="flexTestForm" action="${SampleAction}">
          <ol class="nobullet">
            <li><label class="label flexTestOption" for="${TestValue}"><input type="radio" name="RadioInputName" value="${TestValue}" id="${TestValue}" />    Test Value</label></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="to-right-justify" id="right-justified-id">
            <h5 for="flexTestNotes">Notes</h5>
            <label class="switch" class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" class="right-block"><div class="slider round" ><span class="on">On</span><span class="off">Off</span></div></label>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```